# Enable autocomplete in HTML form using <script>?

Tags: html, forms

I got a form where I'm not allowed to edit the form directly. However I'm able to add  etc. Is it possible to add autocomplete="off"-attribute without editing directly into the form?

This is my form:

```html
    <form action="/action_page.php">
      <input type="text" name="firstname">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

Hope that was understandable.

Comment: Yeah, use `javascript` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `<button>` for the submit instead of `<input>` and give the tag an id .

Try this javascript:

```js
function off_ac(){
  document.getElementById('text_input').autocomplete = 'off';
}
```

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">
      <input id="text_input" type="text" name="firstname">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Autocomplete will be overruled by most browsers. A workaround is to change the text Field to text area. Set it to one row high and x letter Width, and it will look almost like a text Field.